# Jailer exclude tables to be exported

Tags: postgresql, tools

As seen in this [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/246578/118215) I can use jailer in order to export a subset of data into an SQL script.

But in my case I also want to exclude some tables completely from being extracted at all especially on tables relating on the table that I want to extract.

So how I can exclude the unwanted tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable all associations to these unwanted tables.
(Alternatively, but not recommended: remove the unwanted tables from the data model)